# jQuery selector that will select only the direct sibling of the div with the class only the one that was just clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I have mulitple html divs with same classes.

I want a jQuery selector that will select only the direct sibling of the div with the class .profile-list only the one that was just clicked

My html is:

```
<div class="profile-list-contain">
    <ul class="profile-list">
        Content
    <ul>
    <div class="plist-details">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="profile-list-contain">
    <ul class="profile-list">
        Content
    <ul>
    <div class="plist-details">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case when the first profile-list-contain is clicked, i want only the plist-details inside the first profile-list-contain to toggle only.

something like:  `$('.profile-list:clicked + .plist-details').slideToggle();`
but this is invalid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use current elements clicked context `this` along with `.find('.plist-details')` to find element `.plist-details` in it:

```
$('.profile-list-contain').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.plist-details').slideToggle();
});
```